# How to enclose the brackets around a percentage?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment on displaying the numbers of Vowels and Digits in a string. The output is correct, except that I am not sure on how to display the outcome displayed below:

```
Enter a String: testing12345

Number of vowels is: 2 (16.67%)

Number of digits is: 5 (41.67%)
```

When I am working on my code, the outcome is displayed as shown below:

```
Enter a String: testing12345

Number of vowels is: 2()16.67%

Number of digits is: 5()41.67%
```

I would like to know how to enclose the brackets around the percentage, attached below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountVowelDigit {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    

        //Counter variable to store the count of vowels and consonant    
        int vCount = 0, cCount = 0;    
        String inStr;
        int inStrLen;
        double totalDigitPercentage = 0.0;
        double totalVowelPercentage = 0.0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
        inStr = in.next().toLowerCase();
        inStrLen = inStr.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < inStrLen; i++) {    
            char ch = inStr.charAt(i);
            //Checks whether a character is a vowel    
            if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch== 'o' || ch == 'u') {    
                //Increments the vowel counter    
                vCount++;    
            }    
            //Checks whether a character is a consonant    
            else if(ch >= '0' && ch<='9') {      
                //Increments the consonant counter    
                cCount++;    
            }    

            totalVowelPercentage = 100.0*vCount/inStr.length();
            totalDigitPercentage = 100.0*cCount/inStr.length();
        }    

        System.out.println("Number of vowels is: " + vCount + "()" + String.format("%.2f",totalVowelPercentage) + "%");   
        System.out.println("Number of digits is: " + cCount + "()" + String.format("%.2f",totalVowelPercentage) + "%");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Do you understand how you get all the pieces of your string together?

Comment: Do you understand how String concatenation works in Java and what you are doing by writing `+ "()"` for example?

Comment: And i'm quite sure you get the same percentage output for digits and vowels with your current code.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Yes I roughly know what is it about

Answer (score 5):

The format may contain template text, and there is a formated `printf` for `System.out`:

```
    System.out.printf("Number of vowels is: %d (%.2f%%)%n",
            vCount, totalVowelPercentage);
```

- `%%` is the self escaped percentage.
- `%n` is the line separator which with `println` was added automatically at the end. On Windows `\r\n`

The error being having `"()" + String.format(...)` instead of `"(" + S... + ")"`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like below - you just need to shift closing `')'` at end thats it.

```
 System.out.println("Number of vowels is: " + vCount + "(" + String.format("%.2f",totalVowelPercentage) + "%)");   
 System.out.println("Number of digits is: " + cCount + "(" + String.format("%.2f",totalDigitPercentage) + "%)");
```

Comment: While this is approach works, its still a convoluted way when you can use .printf or pack it all into the .format

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solutions. My code is able to work well :)

Comment: @Nordiii whether or not this is convoluted is a lot less important in my opinion than whether or not the answer helps the person asking the question understand what his error was. In that context this answer is doing that job just fine (probably better than the other one).